# Glassfish in a production environment?

Tags: glassfish, production

Do you use Glassfish 2 or v3 in a production environment?

Do you find it robust?

Have you ever been able to find a *complete* set of documentation?

What do you do when you find that Glassfish ignores J2EE standards, like class and anotation scanning?

Comment: GlassFish v3 has been released and appears quite nice.  Oracle has stated they will maintain Glassfish as the reference JEE implementation (they already have WebLogic).

Answer (score 4):

[Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) is Sun's reference standard for a J2EE app server.  V3 supports the new 3.1 standard.  However, it is only a preview.  It is currently scheduled to be released on [Dec 10, 2009](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=GlassFishV3Schedule).  Of course, it can always be dangerous to be a very early adopter in a production environment.  Currently V3 doesn't support JMS or clustering, for example, but they should be in the final release.

I've used V2 in production for about 3 years and I personally like it.  The web admin console makes it very easy to manage (http://localhost:4848, admin, adminadmin), and the performance is good.  Here's one example, where someone benchmarked Glassfish: [Blog](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/glassfish_2_vs_tomcat_6).  Of course, you should search for more examples and your YMMV.  Here's a Sun [document](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16792063/GlassFish-Tomcat) for Glassfish to help Tomcat User.

One last thing that I would add is that Sun ships, and integrates, both Tomcat and Glassfish in their Java IDE [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) so you can easily switch between the two app servers to test your particular app.

Comment: Actually I think that clustering wont be in until 3.1. See slide 34 on this presentation:

http://www.slideshare.net/alexismp/glassfish-v3-en-route-java-ee-6

Answer (score 2):

GlassFish Server V3 or V2 can be used in production environments but the number of users should be less than 1500. Its not very robust and scalable during high load. If used for simple applications GF works perfectly fine, as it is the reference implementation of Java EE standards by Sun which only server to be a guide to other vendors of application servers.

For more complex and high load applications, its better to go to IBM WebSphere Application Server. That's the most robust app server I have seen in my 15 yrs of experience.

Comment: I was happy to agree with Ramesh until he suggested using WebSphere. I've now moved onto Pivotal tc Server 3, and have found it more reliable than Glassfish v2, which I've more recently seen get Session fixation wrong in production, when under not-very-significant load.

Answer (score 1):

Do I use GF in production? no.

Do I find it robust? yes, but I do not tax it very hard.

Have I ever found a complete set of documentation? I think so... the [GlassFish v2.1 docs](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/prod/gf.entsvr.v21?l=en&a=view) and the GlassFish v3 docs (http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/prod/gf.entsvr.v3?l=en&a=view)

What do I do when GlassFish ignores the J2EE standards?  I file an issue here: https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/

Comment: Taxing Glassfish v2 is not a good idea. It can start giving users the HttpResponse from a different HttpSession under load.

Answer (score 1):

Do I use in production? Yes. (Now, using 3.0.1)

Is it robust? Yes. But my point of view is from someone that likes to follow the server's developers community and can try some tricks.

What about documentation? The official one is really good, and the developers blogs are a great plus (http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/). What is maybe far from other communities, at the moment, is the collective experience material (like forums), but I think the mail lists are good enough (http://glassfish.java.net/public/mailing-lists.html).