# Will using Glassfish for production hurt my application in the long run?

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, weblogic

A consultant advised my boss to make us use Weblogic 12. Unfortunately, it's been a pain so far, especially with JMS. Weblogic 12 supports Java EE 6 only (what a letdown). I've been writing JMS on Glassfish and wildfly,Java EE 7, and going back to EE 6 on this matter has been nothing but a distraction.

So, what I want to know is, if we decide to use Glassfish for production, is that such a bad thing? Will we get screwed in the long run?

Comment: This is an opinion based question so I have voted to close. It is unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a bad thing. You won't get screwed...

The only important thing to mention is that Oracle dropped the commercial support for Glassfish.

If the consultant has a different opinion, he should outline the facts leading to this opinion.

**See also:**

- [Glassfish in a production environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684460/glassfish-in-a-production-environment)
- [GlassFish Became A Killer Appserver, Now It Is Just Great: Oracle Drops Commercial Support For GlassFish](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/glassfish_became_a_killer_appserver)
- [Oracle Glassfish Documentation - Running in a Secure Environment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24940/running-in-secure-environment.htm)

Answer (score 2):

GlassFish in production perfectly works.

And if your boss wants to buy support and patches for it have a look at http://www.payara.co.uk/about